# Record a video in opencv only for 30 secs

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

How to record a video in opencv only for 30 seconds. I used the below code but it records video only for 24 seconds? What is the issue?

```
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int ex = 1734701162;

int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{

    VideoCapture cap(0);
    int i_fps = 15;
    time_t start = time(0);

    string OutputVideoPath = "output.mov";
    VideoWriter outputVideo(OutputVideoPath, ex, i_fps, Size(640,480), true);


    if(!cap.isOpened())  {
        cout << "Not opened" << endl; // check if we succeeded
        return -1;
    }

    while ( 1 ) {

        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame;
        outputVideo << frame;
        if ( difftime( time(0), start) == 30) break;

    }

    outputVideo.release();
    cap.release();


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

2 things here:

1. You're checking the walltime. difftime returns a double, so it's highly unlikely that you ever get *exactly* 30 as the outcome. Make it like this instead:
   `if ( difftime( time(0), start) >= 30) break;`
2. You specify 15fps for the VideoWriter, but the time you measure is the time spent *playing* (and writing) the video. (that's totally arbitrary)

If your input video was recorded with a different framerate than 15fps, you've got to take care of that ratio yourself by either dropping or duplicating frames.

You might be better off counting frames and stopping if you reach `30 * 15`.

Comment: Hi I checked it. Now I get 30 sec video. But the capturing ends before 30 secs. i.e., the exe finish running in 30 secs. Cant I sink both? I am in a need to do. So please advice.

Comment: note, that the playback is *not* synchronized to any clock. the time you measure is spent on retrieving & writing a frame. your machine seems to need more than 30 seconds to process a 30sec. piece of video, that's it.  go for counting frames instead then!

Comment: to cut a long story short: imho the idea of timing the playback/write process was a bad idea in the first place. it's got nothing to do with the recorded video sequence